# Google spreadsheet hyperlink to RETURN TO original location on a specific sheet after a jump button pressed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to determine if it is possible to write a script on google sheets that would return a user to the specific cell on a sheet from where they came.  It would be an extension of code like this:

```
function gotolocation2() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("location2");
ss.setActiveSheet(sheet).setActiveSelection("A1");   
}
```

Say the user clicks to jump to here, then wants to return to where they were (ie location1).  I am trying to figure out how that could be done - somehow referencing location1 they left form in the initial function? Or is there a way to do it through the API?  This would behave similar to the MS Excel 'back' 'forward' buttons that can be added to the toolbar.

Obviously, I think this would be limited to tabs within the same google spreadsheet(?)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If the user edited or changed something, you could record what cell the user was in when they edited or changed something.  You'd need to constantly be keeping a record of all this data.  If the user didn't edit or change something, but was just navigating, I don't know how you'd be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the last active cell in to Properties Service and later on return to that cell.

```
function gotolocation2() {
  var properties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var active = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  properties.setProperty("sheet", active.getSheet().getName())
  properties.setProperty("cell", active.getA1Notation());
  ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2").getRange("A1").activate();   
}

function gotolocation1() {
  var properties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var active = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var sheet = properties.getProperty("sheet");
  var cell = properties.getProperty("cell");
  ss.getSheetByName(sheet).getRange(cell).activate();   
}
```